# Can there exist two non-equivalent equivariant actions of a group on vector bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, fibre-bundles

Can there exist two non-equivalent equivariant actions of a group $G$ on vector bundle over a $G$ space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I am miss understanding the question, but it seems the answer is yes.

Take your favorite G-space, mine is $S^1$ with the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action "flip". Then consider the trivial vector bundles $S^1 \times V$, where $V$ is a $G$-representation. In my favorite example $V = \mathbb{R}$ can be either the trivial representation or the sign representation. Taking the diagonal $G$-action gives an equivariant action of the group on the vector bundle. They are distinct for distinct representations (at least in the $S^1$-example) yet the underlying vector bundles are the same if the representations have the same dimension (they are trivial bundles after all).

Comment: Or more simply, replace $S^1$ with a point?

Comment: Of course! yes use a point. It's much easier then the circle. I should have used that from the beginning. 

Answer (score 3):

For an example from Algebraic Geometry, $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ is a homogeneous space for both $GL(2)$ and $SL(2)$. The trivial line bundle and the determinant line bundle are isomorphic as $SL(2)$-equivariant bundles, and therefore as vector bundles, but are non-isomorphic as $GL(2)$-equivariant bundles.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, one can ask whether a group action on a manifold $M$ (sorry, I work primarily in that category) can be lifted to a fibre bundle over $M$.  There are obstructions to the lifting and even if a lifting exists it may not be unique.  The earliest results of this nature I am aware of are in the paper [Lifting compact group actions in fiber bundles](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=461538) by Hattori and Yoshida.  You may also want to look at this more recent article [*Lifts of smooth group actions to line bundles*](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/33/3/351) by Ignasi Mundet, which may contain more recent references.